# "double free or corruption" - free memory on array of structs - C

Tags: c, linked-list, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation, free

im new to C, have to work with it for University and am really struggling with it atm.

We got some code and had to programm a few functions into it, so that they work with what we got.

My Code:

```
int readData(char *path, linkedList *list, meal **menu) {
/* --- Config --- */

int ctr=0;                      //to count parsed lines
int linesCount=1;               //to count lines in file first
char ch;                        //char to check while counting lines
FILE *fp = fopen(path, "r");    //file to read from
FILE *fp2 = fopen(path, "r");    //file to read from
char chunk[128];                //buffer for each line
customerParty *newCustomer;

/* --- Code --- */

//count lines to malloc enough memory afterwards
while((ch=fgetc(fp2))!=EOF) {
    if(ch=='\n')
        linesCount++;
}

//allocate memory
newCustomer = malloc(linesCount * sizeof(customerParty));

//read file line by line, initialize a newCustomer out of each line
while(fgets(chunk, sizeof(chunk), fp) != NULL) {
    parseLine(chunk, &newCustomer[ctr], menu);
    listInsert(list, &newCustomer[ctr]);
    ctr++;
}

//close files
fclose(fp2);
fclose(fp);

return ctr;}
```

and the provided code/class does this (shortened)

```
void listRemove(linkedList *list, customerParty *elem) {

{...} 

elem->next = NULL;

free(elem->name);
free(elem->order);
free(elem);}
```

From gdb i know that the free(elem->order) isn't the problem but the free(elem), but why is it? Why can't it free the memory i allocated?
I always get the "double free or corruption (out)" error.

Help is much appreciated! Thank you!

#edit: thanks for all your help!

what is my code supposed to do?

- get a file and create a newCustomer for every line in that file
- call the parseLine function on each newCustomer (just fills the struct with information from each line)
- call the listInsert function to add it to the list

I'm not allowed to change anything in the listRemove function, they especially said we should program it so their code free's the memory correctly. At the moment my code creates the newCustomer structs and also fills them into the list just perfectly, but the freeing at the end is the problem.
This is the only place i use  malloc, im just trying to create an array of N customerParty's to then fill them.

Comment: We need enough code to replicate the problem. We can't see how these things are allocated so can't tell if they're being freed correctly.

Comment: Given `char ch`, `(ch=fgetc(fp2))!=EOF` can not reliably detect end-of-file because `EOF` is an ***integer*** value that can't fit into a `char`.

Comment: In order to help with memory allocations, all `malloc()` and `free()` related code should be presented in the question. Your question contains more `free` calls that `malloc` calls, which is at least suspicious.

Answer (score 4):

If I have understood correctly in this statement

```
newCustomer = malloc(linesCount * sizeof(customerParty));
```

you allocated an array of linesCount elements (nodes of the list) and then you are passing a pointer to each element to the function `listInsert`.

```
listInsert(list, &newCustomer[ctr]);
```

So you may not delete individual elements of the allocated array  You may delete only the whole array. Otherwise you have undefined behavior when you call free.

You need to create dynamically each node of the list separately and pass a pointer to the allocated dynamically node to the function `listInsert`.

Comment: I thought i was creating them dynamically - so mission failed. Thank you for your advice - i guess this makes sense!

Do you have an example how to create the structs dynamically? I dont really know what i have to search for - what i have atm is what i found when i searched.

Comment: @xEnemyy There are many examples of creating linked lists at SO. For example not so far I answered a question relative to linked lists https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67909681/c-rotate-linked-list-by-user-choice/67910529#67910529

Answer (score 0):

From your code I rather think that you want the array, not the linked list.

```
customerList *add(customerList *customerArray, customerParty *customer)
{
    size_t newSize = customerArray ? customerArray -> size + 1 : 1;
    customerArray = realloc(customerArray, sizeof(*customerArray) + newSize * sizeof(customerArray -> customers[0]));
    if(customerArray)
    {
        customerArray -> size = newSize;
        memcpy(&customerArray -> customers[newsize - 1], customer, sizeof(*customer));
    }
    return customerArray;
}

customerList *removeAtPos(customerList *customerArray, size_t pos)
{
    if(customerArray && customerArray -> size > pos)
    {        
        memmove(&customerArray -> customers[pos], &customerArray -> customers[pos + 1], (customerArray -> size - pos - 1) * sizeof(customerArray -> customers[0]));
        if(customerArray -> size = 1) 
        {
            free(customerArray);
            customerArray = NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            customerArray = realloc(customerArray, sizeof(*customerArray) + (customerArray -> size - 1) * sizeof(customerArray -> customers[0]));
    }
    return customerArray;
}
```